# Any importance to TVS 'parallel' vs 'series' Topology?

Tags: diodes, analog, protection, tvs, reverse-breakdown

I am working with an existing schematic which has bidirectional TVS surge protection, laid out like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frqWml.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The TVS diodes are discrete and have different breakdown voltages. To me, the above configuration makes less sense than:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFXNsP.png)</sup>

These connections make more sense since there is no 'extra' 0.7V (or whatever the forward drop is for the diode) added to the breakdown voltage of the reverse-biased diode, which someone may forget.

Is there any particular reason for putting two discrete TVS diodes in 'series', like the above schematic rather than 'parallel'?

Comment: Putting them parallel and biased as drawn makes one TVS conduct if the voltage over the pair is either over 0.7 V or less than -0.7 V. You could just as well use normal diodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close in the way that you are thinking but you didn't follow that path all the way to the end.

Each uni-polar TVS looks like a standard silicon diode in the forward direction and like a very high-power Zener diode in the reverse direction.

As you said - the reverse-series connection has a rated clamping voltage of the breakdown voltage plus one diode drop. That's exactly correct.

Now examine what happens when you connect the uni-polar TVS devices in reverse-parallel. The devices now look to be standard silicon diodes connected in reverse-parallel. The voltage drop in each direction is now that of a forward-biased silicon diode, or about 0.7 Vdc.

Answer (score 6):

In the anti-parallel configuration of your second diagram, one of the diodes will conduct whenever the source voltage exceeds its forward threshold voltage (0.6 V or so). This is usually not what you want. The reverse breakdown voltage, which is the whole point of a TVS, won't even come into it.